# Python will not patch json in ConnectWise.

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am a little confused why the following will not work.

I am connecting to our ConnectWise API via requests. I get the response and then I parse through to find the tickets I am looking for. I am then trying to PATCH the ticket to change certain information.

Sample json that is returned via API.

```
{
  "id": 12345,
  "summary": "[CompanyName][ComputerName] Disk Space Check - drive G:",
  "recordType": "ServiceTicket",
  "board": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Board1",
  },
  "status": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "NewTicket",
  },  
  "owner": {
  "id": 1,
  "identifier": "",
```

Once I have identified the ticket I need to work with. I try to patch it.

```
def assign_ticket(self, ticket):

    add_resource = [
                   {'op': 'replace', 'path': '/board/name', 'value': 'Board2'},
                   {'op': 'replace', 'path': '/status/name', 'value': 'NewTicket2'},
                   {'op': 'replace', 'path': '/owner/identifier', 'value': 'MyBrainHurts'}
            ]

    r = requests.patch(self.url + self.url_ticket + str(ticket), json=add_resource, headers=self.header)
    print(r.status_code)
```

It returns a 200 status code to indicate everything completely correctly, but only the /owner/identifier field is updated. The other two are not. I have Google'd for several days and tried multiple variations of the code but I do not see why it will not change the board or status. Any ideas?

Comment: Does PATCHing work when performed through non-Python means, e.g., curl?

Comment: That is an excellent question. I hate to admit that I did not think to try that yet. I will go try that now...

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked some of my other code and I'm patching successfully using an array, but I'm using the ID of the resource rather than the name. Try that; instead of /status/name use /status/id and a numerical value.

What is the result of r.text? That should either return the configuration in its new, patched, form or it will tell you why the patch didn't work.